# where does `input(yytext, yyleng)` function come from in flex scanner?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexer

I'm doing Stanford's CS143: Compiler on [edx](https://www.edx.org/learn/computer-science/stanford-university-compilers)
I saw this code from [this repo](https://github.com/skyzluo/CS143-Compilers-Stanford/blob/3f768b6a1252bca2dc6961c2e9e0220eafb9feeb/PA2/cool.flex#L193)

```
 /* string ends, we need to deal with some escape characters */
<STRING>\" {
    std::string input(yytext, yyleng);

    // remove the '\"'s on both sizes.
    input = input.substr(1, input.length() - 2);

    std::string output = "";
    std::string::size_type pos;
    
    if (input.find_first_of('\0') != std::string::npos) {
        yylval.error_msg = "String contains null character";
        BEGIN 0;
        return ERROR;    
    }
```

it's a scanner rule for matching `string constants` in `flex`.
What I don't understand is where does the `std::string input(yytext, yyleng);` from?

I though It could be a flex's routine so I tried to find it in the flex' [manual](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1112/materials/other/manflex.html#:%7E:text=input()%20reads%20the%20next%20character%20from%20the%20input%20stream.). I found this:

```
input() reads the next character from the input stream.
```

But it doesn't seem like what I'm looking for.

So I though it could be from the libraries like they were included on the top of the [file](https://github.com/skyzluo/CS143-Compilers-Stanford/blob/3f768b6a1252bca2dc6961c2e9e0220eafb9feeb/PA2/cool.flex#L12C1-L16C18)

```
#include <cool-parse.h>
#include <stringtab.h>
#include <utilities.h>
#include <string>
```

I gave them a look but haven't found anything.

I'm pretty new into `compiler`, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `input` here is not a function. It's a `std::string`.
Specifically, it's a call of a constructor of `std::string` which takes pointer to character array and its length.

See [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (variant 4).

Comment: Btw, the `input.substr` right after construction is very inefficient. You could just create the string without the first and last character from the start. (`std::string input(yytext + 1, yyleng - 2);`) This would spare copying a (potentially long) string 2 times.

Comment: I don't know about `C` so I don't know a constructor can be called with a defferent name like this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DanhLe This is C++. C doesn't have constructors at all. `input` is not a name of the constructor. It's a name of the variable. The constructor itself doesn't really have a name unless you consider the class name `std::string` to be it.